# Changing View Spams Warnings - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I'm using this code to transition to my Game Over view from my Game view:

```
UIViewController *second = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"gameOverPage"];
second.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Doing this spams this error about 10 times:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <GameOver: 0x14ed5320> on <Game: 0x14ec2370> while
a presentation is in progress!
```

And then it spams this about the same amount:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <GameOver: 0x10c57ade0> on <Game: 0x10c678650> 
whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

If you ignore the errors, it works perfectly fine, but I want to fix my code so that those errors go aways.

Comment: In which method you call the presentation?

Comment: It's just a method that is called when the player hits a block and loses. No special method.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error is pretty specific.  You created `Game`, which is presumably a `UIViewController`, but did not add it to a window, or perhaps it is not in the current key window.  At some point, probably in your App Delegate implementation you should be doing something like this:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = self.yourGameControllerHere;  
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

If `Game` is not the root VC, it should be a child of a VC that eventually parents to the window.

Comment: I have my Main Menu VC (which is the default one), the Game one, and the Game Over one. Please see my post again because I added another error that it's throwing too.